# How to reach element loaded by js after click in mocha

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

I need to click element (dropdown) loaded by js and visible only after clicking element below. My mocha test is throwing:

```
ElementNotInteractableError: element not interactable
```

Can you help?

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver')
const assert = require('assert')
describe('test create node/folder', function(done) {
  this.timeout(30000)
  let driver
  let vars
  beforeEach(async function() {

    driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build()
    vars = {}
  })
  afterEach(async function() {
    await driver.quit();
  })
  it('test name', async function() {
    await driver.get("https://testing-website.com/")

    // Some testing steps representing user behavior navigating the website

    await driver.findElement(By.css(".px-2 > .w-fit > .d-flex > .hover-visible > .hover-visible-el > .mx-2  > .ui-svg-inline"))
    await driver.findElement(By.css(".px-2 > .w-fit > .d-flex > .hover-visible > .hover-visible-el > .mx-2  > .ui-svg-inline")).click()

    // some steps after
  })
})
```

How to simulate mouse click on the element and load the code under?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to sumulate mouse hoover in the following way:

```
    await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(".px-2 > .w-fit > .d-flex > .hover-visible > .hover-visible-el > .mx-2  > .ui-svg-inline")), 30000)
    {
      const hoverLocation = await driver.findElement(By.css(".px-2 > .w-fit > .d-flex > .hover-visible > .hover-visible-el > .mx-2  > .ui-svg-inline"));
      const actions = driver.actions({ bridge: true });
      await actions.move({origin: hoverLocation}).perform();
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).